It is possible to drag and drop the mesh with collider in react three rapier?
I having this problem while doing my project in react three rapier, I need to drag and drop Meshes in the scene, and each of meshes haver their own colliders, apart from moving in axes X and Y, nedd to rotate on Y axes too, I did alot of research, but there no information related.
I did find this codesandbox, but in this situation it can move on X and Y axes but it can't rotate on Y axes,
